# How can I suppress the creation of a plot while calling a function in R?

Tags: r

I am using a function in R (specifically `limma::plotMDS`) that produces a plot and also returns a useful value. I want to get the returned value without producing the plot. Is there an easy way to call the function but suppress the plot that it creates?

Comment: You might try putting `pdf("NULL")` and `dev.off` around your plot function/object.

Comment: Won't that create a PDF file called "NULL"?

Comment: It will.  Sorry about that.  Try calling `suppressWarnings(windows("NULL"))` before your call to your plot function/object.  But note that this solution is Windows-specific.

Comment: @Jota `pdf(file = NULL)` should work, without the quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the function call like this :

```
plotMDS.invisible <- function(...){
    ff <- tempfile()
    png(filename=ff)
    res <- plotMDS(...)
    dev.off()
    unlink(ff)
    res
}
```

An example of call :

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000*6,sd=0.5),1000,6)
rownames(x) <- paste("Gene",1:1000)
x[1:50,4:6] <- x[1:50,4:6] + 2
# without labels, indexes of samples are plotted.
mds <- plotMDS.invisible(x,  col=c(rep("black",3), rep("red",3)) )
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to create a temp file. Could I use /dev/null instead?